# There is a problem with multiple guest requests

Tags: node.js, express, security, next.js

**Next.js/server.js project**

My server.ts file:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as next from 'next';
...
import * as rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import * as config from '../config';

// const apiLimiter = rateLimit({
//     windowMs: 1 * 60 * 1000, // 1 minutes
//     max: 200,
//     message: "Too many requests from this IP"
// });

const routes = require('./nextRoutes');

const app = next({ dev: config.dev });

app.prepare().then(() => {
    const server = express();
    // server.use(apiLimiter);
    ...

    server.get('*', (req, res) => {
        const handle = routes.getRequestHandler(app);
        handle(req, res, req.url);
    });

    server.listen(config.port, (err) => {
        if (err) { throw err; }
    });
})
```

**question 1:** I tried limiting requests to 200 per minute. But this limitation worked for all requests. How can I limit a specific IP address, since it will not work to limit the sessionID, they are all different come? I want to restrict by IP

**question 2:** Is there any way to get the IP address exceeding the limit, some callback inside the given middleware? I looked through the documentation and understand that there is such a way, but I did not understand how to implement it.

Thanks for any answers or ideas!!! Plus in karma. And have a nice day!

Comment: So in fact you don't want to limit by the IP address but the sessionID instead?

Comment: I want to restrict by IP

Comment: I don't understand the problem then - `express-rate-limit` will limit by IP adress by default.

Comment: I tried to set the 200 limit per minute and it worked as if globally, that is, on the ip, but as if in general it had exhausted the limit of requests and threw out 423 for everyone, we checked it in two in production

Comment: Is there a load balancer or something similar in front of your app such that the ip would be the same for all incoming requests?

Comment: Thank you for your question, I check with the system administrator, another person is engaged in this, I do not know anything about this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then using a standard call for this library, I actually enabled the IP restriction and it remains to figure out from which IP is the Node actually receiving the request?